Securing microservices with Spring Security JWT
I would like to build a RESTful microservices architecture where each microservice acts as a resource server. Additionally, there will be an authorization server responsible only for user registration, authentication, and creation and validation of JWT tokens. The architecture will also include a simple gateway service. Therefore, the OAuth2 authorization code flow is not suitable for me since it is based on redirects (oauth2client gateway with TokenRelay filter -> oauth2authorization server etc.).
So, I have created the following components:
1. Authorization Server
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final RsaKeyPairInitializer rsaKeyPairInitializer;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                                       final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        final var authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSet jwkSet() {
        final RsaKeyPair rsaKeyPair = rsaKeyPairInitializer.getRsaKeyPair();
        final var rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeyPair.getPublicKey())
                .privateKey(rsaKeyPair.getPrivateKey())
                .keyID(rsaKeyPair.getId())
                .build();
        return new JWKSet(rsaKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet()));
    }
}

@Tag(name = "Authentication management", description = "Endpoint for registration and login")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {
    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    @Operation(summary = "Register a new user", description = "Register a new user")
    public UserResponseDto register(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegistrationRequestDto requestDto) {
        return authenticationService.register(requestDto);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    @Operation(summary = "Login a user", description = "Login a user")
    public UserLoginResponseDto login(@Valid @RequestBody UserLoginRequestDto requestDto) {
        return authenticationService.login(requestDto);
    }

    @GetMapping("/oauth2/jwks")
    @Operation(summary = "Get jwks", description = "Get jwks configurations")
    public Map<String, Object> getJwks() {
        return authenticationService.getJwks();
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JWKSet jwkSet;

    @Override
    public UserResponseDto register(final UserRegistrationRequestDto registrationDto) {
        validateUserRegistration(registrationDto);

        final User userToSave = userMapper.toModel(registrationDto);
        userToSave.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registrationDto.password()));
        final User savedUser = userRepository.save(userToSave);
        return userMapper.toDto(savedUser);
    }

    @Override
    public UserLoginResponseDto login(final UserLoginRequestDto loginDto) {
        final var authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginDto.email(),
                loginDto.password()
        );
        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
        final String jwt = jwtService.generateToken(authentication);
        return new UserLoginResponseDto(jwt);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getJwks() {
        return jwkSet.toJSONObject(true);
    }

    private void validateUserRegistration(final UserRegistrationRequestDto registrationDto) {
        final String email = registrationDto.email();
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(email)) {
            throw new RegistrationException("User with email " + email + " already exists");
        }
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtServiceImpl implements JwtService {
    private final JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;
    @Value("${jwt.expiration-time}")
    private int expirationTime;
    @Value("${jwt.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    public String generateToken(final Authentication authentication) {
        final String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        final Instant now = Instant.now(Clock.system(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID));
        final JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer(issuer)
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(expirationTime, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim(ROLES_CLAIM, scope)
                .build();
        return jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
}

In short, RSA keys are created or fetched from the database and used to initialize JWKSet and JwtEncoder. The latter encodes JwtClaimsSet and returns a JWT token.
2. Resource Server
All that is needed for configuration is to specify jwk-set-uri (and if necessary to validate the claim iss, then issuer-uri):
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8081
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/api/auth/oauth2/jwks

It is important to note that this endpoint is custom, obtained from the authorization server through this method:
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getJwks() {
    return jwkSet.toJSONObject(true);
}

private void validateUserRegistration(final UserRegistrationRequestDto registrationDto) {
    final String email = registrationDto.email();
    if (userRepository.existsByEmail(email)) {
        throw new RegistrationException("User with email " + email + " already exists");
    }
}

Resource server configs (will be simplified with spring boot 3.3.0+):
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Value("${system-configuration.public-endpoints}")
    private Set<String> publicEndpoints;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers(publicEndpoints.toArray(String[]::new)).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> oauth
                        .jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        final var grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        final var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Tag(name = "User management", description = "Endpoint for managing users")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/me")
    @Operation(summary = "Get current user", description = "Get current user")
    public UserDto getCurrentUser() {
        return userService.getCurrentUser();
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public User getUserByEmail(final String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User with email: " + email + " was not found"));
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto getCurrentUser() {
        final String email = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        return userMapper.toDto(getUserByEmail(email));
    }
}

3. Gateway Service
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: authorization-service
          uri: ${system-configuration.endpoints.authorization-service}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/auth/**
        - id: user-service
          uri: ${system-configuration.endpoints.user-service}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/users/**

Also I've the following classes, which are related to the implementation:
public record UserLoginRequestDto(
        @Email @NotNull String email,
        @NotNull String password
) {
}

public record UserLoginResponseDto(String token) {
}


@FieldMatch(
        first = "password",
        second = "repeatPassword",
        message = "the password fields must match"
)
public record UserRegistrationRequestDto(
        @NotNull @Email String email,
        @NotNull String firstName,
        @NotNull String lastName,
        @NotNull String password,
        @NotNull String repeatPassword
) {
}

public record UserResponseDto(
        Long id,
        String email,
        String firstName,
        String lastName
) {
}

@Converter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RsaPrivateKeyConverter implements AttributeConverter<RSAPrivateKey, String> {
    private final TextEncryptor textEncryptor;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(RSAPrivateKey attribute) {
        var pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(attribute.getEncoded());
        var string = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded())
                + "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
        return this.textEncryptor.encrypt(string);
    }

    @Override
    public RSAPrivateKey convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            var pem = this.textEncryptor.decrypt(dbData);
            var privateKeyPEM = pem
                    .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                    .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            var encoded = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);
            var keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            var keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
            return (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot deserialize private key", throwable);
        }
    }
}

@Converter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RsaPublicKeyConverter implements AttributeConverter<RSAPublicKey, String> {
    private final TextEncryptor textEncryptor;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(RSAPublicKey attribute) {
        var x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(attribute.getEncoded());
        var pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(x509EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded()) +
                "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        return this.textEncryptor.encrypt(pem);
    }

    @Override
    public RSAPublicKey convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            var pem = textEncryptor.decrypt(dbData);
            var publicKeyPEM = pem
                    .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                    .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
            var encoded = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);
            var keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            var keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
            return (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot deserialize public key", throwable);
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class RsaKeysGenerator {

    public RsaKeyPair generateKeyPair(final String keyId,
                                      final Instant created) {
        var keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        var publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        var privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return RsaKeyPair.builder()
                .id(keyId)
                .created(created)
                .publicKey(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        try {
            var keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class RsaKeyPairInitializer {
    private final RsaKeyPairRepository keyPairRepository;
    private final RsaKeysGenerator rsaKeysGenerator;
    private final String keyId;
    @Getter
    private final RsaKeyPair rsaKeyPair;

    public RsaKeyPairInitializer(final RsaKeyPairRepository keyPairRepository,
                                 final RsaKeysGenerator rsaKeysGenerator,
                                 final @Value("${jwt.key.id}") String keyId) {
        this.keyPairRepository = keyPairRepository;
        this.rsaKeysGenerator = rsaKeysGenerator;
        this.keyId = keyId;
        init();
        this.rsaKeyPair = keyPairRepository.findAll().getFirst();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (keyPairRepository.findAll().isEmpty()) {
            generateNewKeys();
        }
    }

    private void generateNewKeys() {
        keyPairRepository.save(rsaKeysGenerator.generateKeyPair(keyId, Instant.now()));
    }
}

@Configuration
public class TextEncryptorConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public TextEncryptor textEncryptor(@Value("${jwt.persistence.password}") String pw,
                                       @Value("${jwt.persistence.salt}") String salt) {
        return Encryptors.text(pw, salt);
    }
}


Question: Is the security implemented correctly according to this approach? I am concerned that JwtDecoder is created based on JWKSet with a public key. Am I correct in understanding that the token can be forged and the resource server will accept it?

Welcome to Code Review! Are you using Spring Authorization Server? You don't share its configuration. Can you explain why are you sharing the public key manually? Also, you didn't tell which Oauth2 grant type you're trying to implement.

"concerned that JwtDecoder is created based on JWKSet with a public key. Am I correct in understanding that the token can be forged" - the purpose of JwtDecoder is to validate the token signature. To do so, it uses the public key provided by the Authorization server. In order to sign a token, you need the private key. The private key is stored on the Authorization server and is not intended to be shared with anyone.

@AlexanderIvanchenko, no, I don't use spring authorization server, I've created a custom common service which generates and validates tokens. So I would say I've got similar to password grant type authorization flow

Got it. What about your client application, is it a public client (mobile or web app)? Also, some bits are still missing, for instance UserDetailsService bean, maybe you can share a link to GitHub repository?

@AlexanderIvanchenko, sure
Custom authorization service - https://github.com/YaroslavYarmoshyk/ab-authorization-service
User service (as resource server) - https://github.com/YaroslavYarmoshyk/ab-user-service
I don't have like a client, only gateway proxy - https://github.com/YaroslavYarmoshyk/ab-gateway-service

I'm ready to share my review. If it's still relevant, can you please edit your question to include the code for the following classes from the authorization server: all DTOs (UserLoginRequestDto, UserLoginResponseDto, UserResponseDto, UserLoginResponseDto), converter of private keys RsaPrivateKeyConverter, and also RsaKeysGenerator and RsaKeyPairInitializer (all these classes are directly related to the security of the application).

@AlexanderIvanchenko, updated the description
